# js split with regex will keep unmatched seperator

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have the following code:

```
console.log('xx,,blue,ffff'.split(/[^\,]+/));
// ["", ",,", ",", ""]

console.log('xx,,blue,ffff'.split('xx'));
//  ["", ",,blue,ffff"]

'xx,,blue,ffff'.match(/[^\,]+/)
// ["xx"]
```

I can not figure out why the result of the first two examples are not same and why split will keep the unmatched comma.

**EDIT: add my orginal thought:**

The `/[^\,]+/` will match `xx` and then the `split` method will split `'xx,,blue,ffff'` with `xx` and will get `["", ",,blue,ffff"]`, but the result is `["", ",,blue,ffff"]` where am i wrong ?

Comment: There are 3 examples in your question.

Comment: What issue do you have with that code? What are your expected results?

Comment: The outputs are as expected. What are you expecting as output?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew pls see my edit. I want to know why the length of the result array of `'xx,,blue,ffff'.split(/[^\,]+/)` is four.

Comment: @ rock321987  I expected the result of `console.log('xx,,blue,ffff'.split(/[^\,]+/));` is the same with `console.log('xx,,blue,ffff'.split('xx'));`

Comment: Please do not add a space between `@` and the user name, the mention is not created that way. Note that `["", ",,blue,ffff"]` (you get) = `["", ",,blue,ffff"]` (you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is

```
console.log('xx,,blue,ffff'.split(/[^\,]+/));
```

It splits the given string as `anything that is not comma`. In your string there are three parts that are not `comma` - `xx`, `blue` and `ffff`. These are delimiters on which string will be split. So you get `"", ",,", ",", ""`.

In your second example

```
console.log('xx,,blue,ffff'.split('xx'));
```

It splits the string on the basis of `xx`. So there are two string one before `xx` which is `empty` and one after `xx` which is `,,blue,ffff`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But `'xx,,blue,ffff'.match(/[^\,]+/)` only gets `["xx"]`, so will `'xx,,blue,ffff'.split(/[^\,]+/)` be equal to `'xx,,blue,ffff'.split('xx')` ? Note that i did't add the global match flag.

Comment: @Aflext Pardon me if I misinterpreting your comment but how can `xx,,blue,ffff'.split(/[^\,]+/)` and `xx,,blue,ffff'.split('xx')` be equal if their results are different

Comment: @Aflext The first split works as `anything that is not comma`. So it splits on the basis of three different delimiters. The second split works only when there is specific string as delimiter which is `xx` and nothing else

Comment: I thought that `'xx,,blue,ffff'.match(/[^\,]+/)` gets `["xx"]`, so would `'xx,,blue,ffff'.split(/[^\,]+/)` be equal to `'xx,,blue,ffff'.split('xx')` ?  Dose the `split` method will  use the regex `/[^\,]+/` to get the matches of the string `'xx,,blue,ffff'`  first and then split the string `'xx,,blue,ffff'` with the matches ?

Comment: @Aflext Well I don't know about whether the `string is matched first and then splitted`

Comment: @Aflext This will be a good question to ask in newer thread..You can accept this answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

> I can not figure out why the result of the above two examples are not
>   same and why split will keep the unmatched comma

`String.split` results doesn't keep matched results since it splits the input string from it (by treating the matched items as separator).

If you don't want comma to come in results, you shouldn't negate it. Try this

```
console.log('xx,,blue,ffff'.split(/[,]+/));
```

I removed `\` from `\,` to keep only `,`